# Daily load of weekly records in elastic through logstash ignoring repeated records

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm totally new to elastic and logstash, we are currently evaluating it, expecting to use it for some of our data needings, and I have to say that it's going quite well up to date.

Now I have a doubt and I cannot find a clear answer on the official documentation.

We have an url where we create on demand a json with environmental data for the last 7 days. Those data are updated hourly, so if I check it on monday at 6am it will contain data from monday at 5am to last tuesday at 6am, and if I check it on tuesday at 14pm it will contain data from tuesday at 13pm to last wednesday at 14pm.

I want to load those data on elastic periodically, let's say on a daily basis, but I don't want to repeat values that I've already loaded. I mean, the first time my logstash pipeline executes it will have to transfer data for the last seven days, but if it fires again a day later, it only should transfer records from the last day, ignoring the records of the 6 previous days that already are loaded on the index.

I've been able to load records from the url into elastic index, but I cannot see how to configure the pipeline to avoid those repeated data.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I will appreciate so much.

Comment: Are you using the `http_poller` input to fetch the JSON?

Comment: Yes, that's how we're fetching data from the url

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to handle this on the side that serves that URL where you could give a date interval to retrieve instead of needlessly retrieving useless data every time.

But if this is not an option, you have different ways of achieving what you want in Logstash.

Also, you need the exact same thing as provided by the [`jdbc` input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html), i.e. something that [records the last value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_predefined_parameters) of a certain field in a local file, unfortunately the `http_poller` input doesn't support that... yet... because [an issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http_poller/issues/51) about this very need has been posted in... 2016!!

One way is to use the [`environment` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-environment.html) in order to load an environment variable that would contain the date of the last load for instance. After each run you need to make sure that the environment variable is updated so that its value can be picked up during the next call.

Another way is to use the [`memcached` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-memcached.html) to store that value, but I think it's a bit far fetched to install and maintain memcached just for a single value.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it, the idea is to store the last date/hour recorded as an environment variable, so when next execution fires, it will be able to avoid transferring records with dates previous to the value recorded in the variable. Should we use filter plugin to accomplish this? Or there is any way to filter data just within http_poller?

Comment: The idea is that the environment variable value will be stored in a field inside the `@metadata`(say `["@metadata"]["last_run"]`) of each event and then you can use that field value in the filter section in an if condition to [`drop`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) the event if it pre-dates the last_run value.

Comment: I'm having some trouble to update the environment variable "after" all the processing of the run is done. It's that even possible? Keep in mind that I cannot update it after each event, or I could drop valid events before they were managed. I somewhat need to use one current value to maintain highest date in current run (lets call it current_run), while dropping every event where date is lesser than last_run, and after all events are processed, update last_run with current_run. Any idea?